# Execução de script(js) externo em pagina online

Tags: javascript, html5, aplicação-web, automatização

Desejo executar um script(JS) especifico para a exclusão de alguns elementos da pagina que considero poluição visual; e atrapalham minha navegabilidade em especifico. ( É o site da universidade, então não tenho escolha se não usa-lo )

O script está pronto, faz tudo que desejo e funciona. Porem toda vez que entro na pagina ou atualizo tenho que: abrir o console, colar o script e então executar para ter o resultado que desejo.

Existe alguma forma de automatizar esse processo para toda vez que eu acessar "x-URL" ele executar automaticamente ?
Se sim, qual o termo correto que eu deveria utilizar nas pesquisas do Google para encontrar ?

Onde teria mais informações a respeito ? ( Vi sobre o [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/), porem até o momento ele não se encaixa )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

você pode usar o plugin do chrome Tampermonkey
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=pt-BR
com ele você pode criar scripts próprios e programa-los para executar automaticamente quando uma url específica for lançada no browser

Comment: Obrigado! Irei aplicar essa ferramenta aqui. A  possível solução é melhor do que eu imaginei que seria, é sempre um misto de sensações conhecer alguma coisa nova que pode vir a ser utilizável. =)

Comment: @AlexSandro caso esta resposta tenha resolvido seu problema é recomendável marcá-la como solução.